# .NET PropertyGrid Collection Editor and List<T>

Tags: .net, propertygrid

I'm using the PropertyGrid control in a WinForms application. The window itself binds to a class that contains a list of objects. While I'd prefer it if the grid just expanded and let the user modify the items like a tree-view, I'll settle for the collection editor *if* it will stop listing the members as "Roswell.Windows.Command.Model" (the fully-resolved class name).

I have appplied the DisplayName attribute to both the containing property and the class itself, but the collection editor window itself seems to ignore it.

(FWIW, this is .NET 3.5 in VStudio 2008.)

Any suggestions? I've googled (and SO'd!!) until I'm blue in the face.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the `ToString` method to provide a nicer value (C# example)

```
class MyClass
{
    public string SomeValue { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("SomeValue={0}", this.SomeValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! Any ideas how I get the thing to show up as an expandable list in the grid itself, rather than relying on the collection editor?

Comment: I don't know from the top of my head to achieve that with an array, but you should research into implementing a TypeConverter (as suggested by leppie) and a UI Type Editor.

Answer (score 2):

You can override `ToString()`

- or -

Implement a `TypeConvertor` for your class or property.

Comment: That did the trick. Of course, it was a bit more complicated than I expected, but it certainly worked. I'd vote you up again if I could!!

Comment: @Mike - did you go into TypeConverter at all? if so, can you provide links, code, or articles describing the steps involved?